Playwright tests are giving error running in Azure DevOps CI
I have the following:
setup:
Playwright
Tyscript
Azure DevOps CI

Versions:
"@playwright/test": "^1.45.3",
"@types/node": "^22.0.0",
"chai": "^5.1.1",
"typescript": "5.5.4"
"playwright-core": "1.45.3"

I am providing some relevant details here
package.json
"test:stage:regression": "tsc;cross-env test_env=stage npx playwright test --config=playwright.config.ts --project chromium --grep-invert \"(?=.*@sprint)|(?=.*@system)\"",

playwright.config.ts
workers: process.env.CI ? 4 : undefined,

{
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        storageState: 'playwright/.auth/user.json'
      },
      testDir: './src/tests/regression',
      dependencies: ['setup'],
      teardown: 'global-teardown'
},

Note: I have separated my project between regression & system tests.
I have many spec files which I separated based on features, some are under folders and some are under sub-folders.
Describing the Issue
When I run my tests locally, it runs just fine and executes all the tests properly.
When I trigger the tests ro run on Azure CI, few files run and then it starts failing
 Test timeout of 50000ms exceeded while running "beforeEach" hook.

  12 |   
  13 |
> 14 |     test.beforeEach(async ({ request, page }) => {
     |          ^
  15 |       const loginFlow = new LoginFlow(page);
  16 |       await loginFlow.goToHome();

When I try to run the same regression suite locally it runs fine.
And, when I try to run these tests using only a single spec file it works fine well.
    test.describe(
  'describe tests here with a description',
  { tag: ['@foo', '@bar', '@regression'] },
  async () => {

I am using following in my yaml file:
- script: |
    npm run ${{ parameters.test_environment }}:${{ parameters.namespace }}:${{ parameters.test_suite }}
  displayName: "Run Playwright tests on ${{ parameters.test_environment }}"
  env:
    CI: 'true'

Any help in resolving this issue is really appreciated, because I have been spending almost more than a week to fix this issue and it seems that a few times its working and mostly not.
I tried to provide as much information as possible, happy to share any more to help debug this issue. :)
Thanks!
I have tried various grep, grep invert options to run these tests.
I have also considered running the tests from project level.
I have installed all the latest versions too.
Used all possible ways to describe the tags too.
I am expecting it to run on CI as it is running locally
Yaml files
We have splitted our workflow into 2 separate files in its own repos in GIT.
This is from automation repo
schedules:
  - cron: "0 5 * * 1-5"
    displayName: Weekday run
    branches:
      include:
        - main
    always: true

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: xyz-pipelines
      type: git
      name: xyz-pipelines
      ref: refs/heads/main

trigger:
  - main

parameters:
  - name: node_version
    type: string
    default: 20.11.1
  - name: run_sonarqube
    type: boolean
    default: true
  - name: XXX_data
    type: boolean
    default: false
  - name: XXX_cache
    type: boolean
    default: false
  - name: test_environment
    type: string
    default: test
    values:
      - test
      - dev
      - acc
  - name: namespace
    type: string
    default: abc
    values:
      - abc
      - abc2

variables:
  - template: pipeline-variables.yaml@xyz-pipelines
  - group: 'xyz Credentials'
  - name: NODE_VERSION
    value: ${{ parameters.node_version }}

  - template: e2e-XXX-XXX-template.yaml@xyz-pipelines
    parameters:
      node_version: ${{ parameters.node_version }}
      sonarqube_project: "SONAR_XXX-e2e-tests"
      run_sonarqube: ${{ parameters.run_sonarqube }}
      XXX_data: ${{ parameters.XXX_data }}
      XXX_cache: ${{ parameters.XXX_cache }}
      test_environment: ${{ parameters.test_environment }}
      namespace: ${{ parameters.namespace }}
      test_suite: regression
      stage_name: regression_test
      display_name: "Regression tests on ${{ parameters.test_environment }}"
      condition: not(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'))
  
  - template: e2e-XXX-XXX-template.yaml@xyz-pipelines
    parameters:
      node_version: ${{ parameters.node_version }}
      sonarqube_project: "SONAR_XXX-e2e-tests"
      run_sonarqube: ${{ parameters.run_sonarqube }}
      XXX_data: ${{ parameters.XXX_data }}
      XXX_cache: ${{ parameters.XXX_cache }}
      test_environment: ${{ parameters.test_environment }}
      namespace: ${{ parameters.namespace }}
      test_suite: system
      stage_name: system_test
      display_name: "System tests on ${{ parameters.test_environment }}"
      depends_on:
        - regression_test
      condition: |
       and(
        or(
          always(),
          in(dependencies.regression_test.result, 'Skipped')
        ),
        in(
          variables['Build.Reason'],
            'Schedule', 'Manual', 'IndividualCI'
          )
        )

This is into another repo e2e-XXX-XXX-template.yaml@xyz-pipelines
parameters:
  - name: node_version
    type: string
    default: "20.16.0"
  - name: run_sonarqube
    type: boolean
    default: false
  - name: XXX_data
    type: boolean
    default: false
  - name: XXX_cache
    type: boolean
    default: false
  - name: sonarqube_project
    type: string
  - name: test_environment
    type: string
    default: test
    values:
      - test
      - dev
      - acc
  - name: namespace
    type: string
    default: mes
    values:
      - abc
      - abc2
  - name: test_suite
    type: string
    default: regression
    values:
      - regression
      - system
      - sprint
  - name: stage_name
    type: string
    default: e2e_tests
  - name: display_name
    type: string
    default: "End to end tests"
  - name: depends_on
    type: object
    default: []
  - name: condition
    type: string
    default: ""

stages:
  - stage: ${{ parameters.stage_name }}
    displayName: ${{ parameters.display_name }}
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.depends_on }}
    condition: ${{ parameters.condition }}
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest

    jobs:
      - job: test
        displayName: "end to end tests"

        steps:
          # Install npm and set registry
          - template: templates/typescript/steps_npm_setup.yaml

          - script: |
              npm ci
            displayName: "Install dependencies"

          - ${{ if eq(parameters.run_sonarqube, true) }}:
              - template: templates/xxx/steps_sonarqube_prepare.yaml
                parameters:
                  programming_language: "typescript"
                  sonarqube_project: ${{ parameters.sonarqube_project }}
              - template: templates/xxx/steps_sonarqube_analyze.yaml
                parameters:
                  sonarqube_project: ${{ parameters.sonarqube_project }}

          - script: |
              mkdir -p playwright/.auth
            displayName: "Create directory for local storage"

          - script: |
              npx playwright install --with-deps
            displayName: "Install Playwright Browsers"

          - task: KubeloginInstaller@0

          - task: Kubernetes@1
            inputs:
              connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
              kubernetesServiceEndpoint: kubernetes-${{ parameters.test_environment }}
              command: 'login'

          - script: |
              kubectl port-forward -n ${{ parameters.namespace }} services/xxx-xxx 8001:80 &
            displayName: "Configure port forwarding"

          - script: |
              kubectl port-forward -n ${{ parameters.namespace }} service/mongodb-svc 123321:123321 &
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=xxxPassword;issecret=true]$(kubectl get secrets -n ${{ parameters.namespace }} xxxdb-secret -o go-template='{{ .data.xxx_ADMIN_PASSWORD | base64decode }}')"
            displayName: "Add forwarding for xxxDB"

          - ${{ if eq(parameters.xxx_cache, true) }}:
              - script: |
                  kubectl apply -f kubernetes-job-xxx-clear.yaml -n ${{parameters.namespace}} --force
                displayName: "xxx Cache"

          - ${{ if eq(parameters.xxx_data, true) }}:
              - script: |
                  kubectl apply -f kubernetes-job-cleanup.yaml -n ${{parameters.namespace}} --force
                displayName: "xxx Data"

          - script: |
              npm run ${{ parameters.test_environment }}:${{ parameters.namespace }}:${{ parameters.test_suite }}
            displayName: "Run Playwright tests on ${{ parameters.test_environment }}"
            env:
              CI: 'true'
              AUTH_USERNAME: 'xxx-admin'
              ${{ if eq(parameters.namespace, 'mes') }}:
                ${{ if eq(parameters.test_environment, 'test') }}:
                  AUTH_PASSWORD: '$(xxx_ADMIN_TEST)'
                ${{ elseif eq(parameters.test_environment, 'dev') }}:
                  AUTH_PASSWORD: '$(xxx_ADMIN_DEV)'
                ${{ elseif eq(parameters.test_environment, 'acc') }}:
                  AUTH_PASSWORD: '$(xxx_ADMIN_ACC)'
              ${{ elseif eq(parameters.namespace, 'abc') }}:
                ${{ if eq(parameters.test_environment, 'test') }}:
                  AUTH_PASSWORD: '$(xxx_ADMIN_TEST2)'
             
          - script: 'kill $(lsof -t -i:8001) $(lsof -t -i:27017)'
            displayName: "xxx forwardings"
            condition: always()
            continueOnError: true

          - task: PublishTestResults@2
            displayName: "Publish E2E test results"
            condition: succeededOrFailed()
            inputs:
              testResultsFiles: e2e*.xml
              testResultsFormat: JUnit
              searchFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test-results/
              failTaskOnFailedTests: true

          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            displayName: "Publish screenshots, videos and trace files of failed tests"
            condition: succeededOrFailed()
            inputs:
              targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/test-results/

Screenshot from the folder structure
enter image description here

Can you provide the detailed bugging logs of the failed pipeline run, and the complete YAML of the pipeline? What agent are you using to run the pipeline, Microsoft-hosted agents, or Self-hosted agents installed on your own machines?

You mentioned that the same 'npm run' command can work fine for the same project when you manually run it on your local machine. If you try to install a  self-hosted agent on the same machine to run the pipeline, does it also work? What are the detailed versions of Node.js and npm installed on your local machine?

What does the file structure of your project look like? When you manually run the command on your local machine, do you run the command in which folder/directory of the project? When you run the command in pipeline, do you ensure that it is running in the same folder/directory of the project as that on local?

We are using Microsoft-hosted-runner
My local has:
node -v
v20.11.1
npm -v
10.2.4

In Azure too it fails on beforeEach block and the UI is staying on the login screen.

Again, What does the file structure of your project look like? Which folder/directory of the project do you run the command in when you manually run on your local machine? When you run the command in pipeline, do you run in the same folder/directory of the project as that on local?

What detailed command lines do you on the your local machine? Try to directly run the exact same command lines in pipeline to see if it can work? Did you try using a self-hosted agent installed on your local machine?

What do you mean "In Azure too it fails on beforeEach block and the UI is staying on the login screen. "?

Thanks @BrightRan-MSFT for your suggestions.
It seems that the issue was when we were running our tests in multiple workers and the way we were handling the internal token which we use in our tests.
The issue was when it was running with the multiple workers, tests were having problem in sharing the sessions and giving us the login screen.
We just applied the fix to check if its a login screen apply the login again.

OK. Go ahead. And if you have any update, you can comment here or post answer to show how you fix the issue. @RamandeepSingh
